# Spring Custom Validator + Annotated Constraints

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I have a Spring Boot 1.3.7 project which uses entity validations like @NotNull.

This is great because one can specify "@Valid @RequestBody Pojo pojo" and have 'pojo' automatically validated. Very cool.

However, sometimes you need more complex logic where a custom validator (a class which implements Validator) is appropriate.

This can be done too. One makes a class, marks it with @Component and has it implement "Validator".

However, to use it, one must declare, in each controller they wish to mix the two types of validators:

```
@InitBinder
public void initializeBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.addValidators(theValidator);
}
```

This strikes me as the kind of thing Spring Boot should be automatically doing -- just component scan for all my validators and use them with the binder.

Am I missing something? Does this really need to be declared in every controller?

Thanks!